# Cannot append the code to the other page of asp.net mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I seperated the data into to page, one for menu and another for contents of each other.
I have using jquery to append data that I got from database to  in my web page. 
The menu page is using ItemModels and for the content page is using BrandModels.

This is the content page :

```
 <div id="brand-item">

    <% if (blahblah == true){ %>
         <a href="<%: brand_url %>" id="brand_id">
              <img src="<%:Model.Item[i].Brand.Image%>" width = "85px"/>
         </a>
    <% } else { %>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <% } %>
 </div>
```

This is what I tried in Menu page :

```
 if ($("#brand_id").length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("brand_id").innerHTML = '<img 
    src="<%:Model.Item[i].Brand.Image%>" width = "85px"/>';  
 } else {
     document.getElementById("brand-item").innerHTML =
    "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
 }
```

Then it is error : BrandModels does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument.
But in fact, I just want to append this line of html and asp.net code in menu page to the content page.

Could any one tell me how to solve this?

Thanks so much and welcome to all your answers.

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

the problem must be because of 'Model.Item[i].Brand.Image' in Jquery, Array index 'i' here doesn't have any value. try to check if index 'i' is holding value here

Comment: Uhh yes I see, I modified it. But it's still error like before modify.

Comment: try to alert the value of i and see if you are getting any value for it. if not try to hard code i with 0 and check if you are getting desired output

Comment: Yes of course, I changed from i to 1, but it still getting error : BrandModels does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument.

Comment: only reason i can think now is that your BrandModels object doesnt have reference to Item object in it. Just check your BrandModel class definition

Answer (score 0):

Your content page is most likely strongly typed for type BrandModel.
How did you set up your Menu page? Is it openly typed (dynamic)?

If you don't strongly type  your page, you will run into errors like this because the page does not know how the data inside the Model is contructed.

Comment: It is a partial views, and here `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Web.ModelView.BrandModels>" %>`